# Bootstrap affix resizes strangely on Firefox only

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to affix & scrollspy a menu to the top of a site ( http://www.vaccinateyourdoctors.org/ ) as the user scrolls down the page.

Using the Bootstrap Docs as an example, I'm calling:

```
!function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.navbar').affix({
            offset: $('.navbar').position() });
    });
```

This works perfectly in Chrome/Safari, but in Firefox only, the responsive control seems to kick in, and resizes the navbar to be much narrower.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

[Among other things, I've tried the Bootstrap 2.3.0-wip git branch, but that doesn't seem to fix this problem.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of poking, it appears that Bootstrap plays poorly when navbars are affixed. This is because the "position:fixed;" property, as applied by the "affix" plugin, effectively hides the inherited properties of the navbar.

I have worked around this in an ugly way, by dynamically and forcibly resizing the window, via:

```
$(window).bind("resize", function(){ $('#target').css("width",$('#target').width()); })
$(window).bind("scroll", function(){ $('#target').css("width",$('#target').width()); })
```

Edit: Marking this as answered. I may follow up when bootstrap 2.3.0 is released.

Comment: Still an issue at v3.3.5